# How to make a mesh follow the curvature of another deformed mesh?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm trying to find a fast way to snap one mesh to the curvature of another deformed plane. As of now, I'm drawing the path out by hand and manually adjusting the height of each vertice to follow my ground plane. Surely there must be an easier way through modifiers or something?

Here you can see what I'm doing. I'm adding banners around the track which need to follow the curvature of the ground.

[image: Banner Example]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Try using the [shrinkwrap modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html?highlight=shrinkwrap)

Comment: When I try to add that modifier, I can't select the 'ground' plane as a target.

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: What other information would you like?

Comment: Sharing the blend file would be a great start. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link to your question